# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch as full text engine for my rails pet project app for my `Post` model. In my `posts_controller.rb` index action:

```
    def index
        if params[:query]
            @posts = Post.search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).records
        else
            @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')  
        end
    end
```

Where, if a query param is present he should filter the results and present it to the `index.html.erb`.

What happens is I get

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound: [404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[posts] missing]","status":404}
```

I ran the `bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Post'` but I still get the same error.

In the words of Marvin Gaye, What's going on?

Comment: Is the import task supposed to create the index for the model if it doesn't exist, or does it assume that it exists?

Comment: It creates an index even if I created one previously

Comment: Did you confirm (using `curl` or a tool like elasticsearch-head) that the `posts` index exists?

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue @tveira

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Post' FORCE=true
```

Note `FORCE=true`.

Answer (score 1):

This Error came for me as well, and i resolved it through following,

go to Rails Console - CTRL , and then create index at your MODEL,

```
MODEL_NAME.import force: true
```